# Using nHibernate, how can I get the newly inserted ID during an Add?

Tags: nhibernate

When I am adding a new row in the database, I noticed the Add method returns `void`.

Is it possible to get the newly created row's ID returned in the add operation?

Comment: Which generator type are you using (there is more to this than a simple answer)? Also, which "Add" method are you referring to? Is this some kind of repository implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call session.Save() on your entity, your entity should have the Id modified.

You probably want to check your nhibernate configuration if your save is occurring immediately or if your saving is batching. If it's batching, then you'll need to commit (or flush, someone will correct this... hopefully) your session.